# ASA5505 switchport command

Tags: cisco-asa, firewall

I've been learning how to use ASA5505 but I faced this thing: When I try to assign Ethernet0/1 with vlan 1, which is the inside network, I see no change in the answer of `sh int ip bri` or `sh run`. Why this could be happening? I do not see anything wrong with my firewall.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

VLAN 1 (`switchport access vlan 1`) is the default. As such, it will not normally show in the config.

`show switch vlan` is the command to see what vlans are defined, and what ports are assigned to them.

The interface list will never show any IP configuration for the ethernet ports because they are part of a switch. (and you cannot `no switchport` them into routed interfaces.) All layer-3 configuration is via VLAN interfaces.

Comment: The default I got is VLAN2 is assigned to e0/0. However I want to assign VLAN1 to e0/1 but when I used the command switchport access vlan 2 on e0/1 nothing happens. Neither I see an error coming up nor the assignment is done.

Comment: Yes, the default system configuration (booted without any config) is E0/0 is vlan 2 (outside). The "ios" default for an interface is vlan 1, which is why `sh run` shows vlan 2 on e0/0 and nothing on the other interfaces. If you enter the correct CLI configuration commands, it will switch vlans: conf t<cr>int e0/1<cr>swi a v 2<cr>